# Constructing a specific class of functions

Tags: functions, derivatives

Consider a class of bounded functions with bounded third derivatives, i.e.,
$$
\mathcal{F}=\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:\|f\|_{\infty}<\infty,\|f'''\|_{\infty}\le 1\}.
$$
If $f\in\mathcal{F}$, then (1) $f(x+c)\in\mathcal{F}$ for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and (2) $c^{-3}f(cx)\in\mathcal{F}$ for any $c\ne 0$.

However, it is not clear what happens to the first and the second derivatives of such functions (except that they are also bounded by Kolmogorov's inequality). Is there a way to restrict $\mathcal{F}$ such that $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ are **uniformly** bounded over the modified $\mathcal{F}$ and properties (1) and (2) hold?

Comment: What kind of restriction are you looking for? If $f \in \cal F$ with $f'(0) \ne 0$ then the derivative of $c^{-3}f(cx)$ at zero can become arbitrary large.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, it looks like (1) and (2) together are incompatible with what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\cal F$ is any family of differentiable functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ and $\cal F$ contains any non-constant function, then $\Vert f' \Vert_\infty$ is *not* uniformly bounded.

The reason is that if $f \in \cal F$ with $f'(a) \ne 0$ then the function $g(x) = c^{-3}f(c(x-a))$ is also in $\cal F$, with $g'(0) = c^{-2}f'(a)$, and that can become arbitrarily large.

In the same way one can see that if $\cal F$ contains any non-linear function then $\Vert f'' \Vert_\infty$ is not uniformly bounded.